# Error on printIN function for groovy

Tags: groovy

I am fairly new to java programming and I am trying to learn groovy right now. 
I am getting this weird error when I am entering a simple line of code of hello world.

[image]

I am buffered. I believe I have set the environment variables correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the method name wrong

It's `println` not `printIn`

If you look at the exception, it tells you what's wrong, and a list of possible solutions

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are using the wrong letter:

`println "hello"`

with  "L" lowercase